# STM32 and HAL function GetTick()

Tags: c++, stm32, hal

Implicit declaration of function 'HAL_GetTick'. Can you tell me or give me a link for library, where I can find declaration of this function.

Comment: I usually find the function declared as _weak in the stm32f7xx_hal.c for an stm32f7. Of course it depends on the stm32 you are using.

Comment: Mine is STM32F10x

Comment: Then it the __weak declaration should be in stm32f1xx_hal.c

Comment: @Marech no - never in .c file. .c files are not for include

Answer (score 1):

The function is nearly the same at every device I am currently working on an F4 so I will provide the definition I have :

```
/**
  * @brief Provides a tick value in millisecond.
  * @note This function is declared as __weak to be overwritten in case of other 
  *       implementations in user file.
  * @retval tick value
  */
__weak uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void)
{
  return uwTick;
}
```

The obvious question is what the hell is uwTick? it is just a volatile uint_32 that get incremented whenever the `HAL_IncTick` is called. The Hal_IncTick is called from the `SysTickHandler` that is called as an interrupt.