# HAL_GetTick() always returns 0

Tags: stm32, hal, stm32cubeide

I'm currently working on a project with an existing codebase where HAL_GetTick() works in some places, but when I try to call the function in other files it returns 0.
HAL_Delay() does work for some reason.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Do your homework: use a debugger, put breakpoints, compare the working and the non working code. `HAL_getTick` probably uses the SysTick. Did you check the SysTick is well enabled ?

Comment: I'm working with a blackbox system, I can't put breakpoints wherever I want. I have checked SysTick and it seems to work fine.

Comment: You wrote "I call the function in other files": isn't it C files calling C functions ?

Comment: HAL_GetTick is doing nothing but returning a global variable that is incremented in the SysTick handler. Check in your vectot table that the right HAL function is set for Systick handler and that the systick is well enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to mention that I also use LoRaWAN. Apparently LoRaWAN also has functions like HAL_InitTick() and HAL_Delay(). I've come to the conclusion that LoRaWAN somehow overrides the timer.

How I fixed this was by going into mlm32I0xx_hal_msp.c and redefine HAL_GetTick():

```
uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void){
   return HW_RTC_Tick2ms(HW_RTC_GetTimerValue());
}
```

Hopefully I can help someone else with this solution.

Comment: This fixed it for me too in a LoRaWAN app. The library function has a `_weak` directive on it so instead of changing in there you can also just put your replacement function in your application code so it doesn't get lost during a library upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that your codebase may have an override for that function. See this post about HAL_GetTick():
[STM32 and HAL function GetTick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241493/stm32-and-hal-function-gettick)

As an alternative you can do the following. If you know the frequency of a timer you can use the following code snippet:

```
const uint32_t freq = 1000000; // Freq in Hz
uint32_t get_ticks() 
{
    uint32_t ticks = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim2);
    return ticks;
}
double ticks_to_seconds(uint32_t ticks)
{
    double seconds = (double) ticks/freq;
    return seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The internal (global) tick counter variable used by the HAL is incremented in an ISR. If you happened to disable IRQs without, the counter won't be incremented any more. The same applies if you didn't enable interrupts at all since startup.

Note: You reported the (reproducible?) result value `0`, which hints that the tick counter has *never* been incremented since power-up. This points us to the assumption that you forgot to

- enable the underlying interrupt (`SysTick` unless you selected some `TIM`, e.g., in CubeMX)
- enable interrupts globally
- retain the CubeHAL `SysTick`/`TIMx` handler code after you replaced it by your own (<-- less realistic option...).

Comment: I initialised the HAL with HAL_Init, I don't know what you mean by 'enable interrupts globally'

Comment: I meant, you have to make sure the timer interrupt (either *SysTick* or a *TIM* instance) can actually trigger. Besides activation/prio for each interrupt vector, there is a global setting to enable/disable interrupts dynamically from SW.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:

I had this problem [ *HAL_GetTick()* always returned 0 ] when I programmed my code on *Sector2* of Flash, which is non-default sector. (Note: Default Sector is Sector0). As a result, I had lost my interrupt handlers.

By programing on *Sector2*, Interrupt **VECTOR TABLE** also had been programmed on *Sector2*, and I had to notify the hardware from this change.

So I changed the value of **VECT_TAB_OFFSET** to point to Sector2. (**VECT_TAB_OFFSET** is defined in ***system_stm32f4xx.c*** OR other equivalent files depending on your MCU)

[image: Note: 0x00008000 is offset of Sector2, from the Base address which is 0x08000000]

Answer (score 0):

I reconfigured the interrupt vector and it can be used. You can check whether the value of the register has been updated according to the SysTick timer (STK) section of the programming manual.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).